# what's the difference between those two icons in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Looks like both are folders, why in different icons

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the documentation on what the various icons are:

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-icons.htm

Comment: Specifically top icon is a package only containing non Java resources and bottom icon is a folder

Answer (score 1):

The first one represents an empty package, a package includes code. The second one is just a folder in your project directory, which can include other things such as resources etc.

Answer (score 1):

Upper icon is about the package structure  .Lower icon is the actual directory tree in your hard-disk.

Suppose you set the source folder of a project to be `src` .Inside `src` folder , you define a package called `com.stackoverflow.package1` , then in your hard-disk , you will have the following file structure `src\com\stackoverflow\package1` . So the upper icon will just show one icon represent the `com.stackoverflow.package1` package , while the lower icon shows the actual file structure  `src\com\stackoverflow\package1` in a directory  tree view , just like what you see in the window explorer.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse often does that kind of thing to indicate that whatever it is a different kind of folder ... or a different view on the same folder.

I don't recognize the first icon, but it looks like the Eclipse Java Package icon overlaid with a marker ("adornment") to say it is under source-code control.

Answer (score 0):

The upper icon is a Java package. So it's a folder, too, but with a special meaning that the Eclipse recognizes and displays differently.